# How can i save the page as pdf as soon as it has been requested?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I want to download the page as pdf as soon as it has been requested. 
Here is my scripts :

```
        <script>
            pdfdoc.fromHTML($('#container').html(), 10, 10, {
                'width': 110,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            pdfdoc.save('Invoice.pdf');
        </script>
```

But the console is giving an error 
Uncaught ReferenceError: pdfdoc is not defined
    at ?id=5:435

 i have already linked the script in the header

 How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a variable pdfdoc var doc = new jsPDF();  and also you need to add jspdf.min.js file.

Try this below Code:

```
<div id="content">
    <h3>Sample h3 tag</h3>
    <p>Sample pararaph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {   
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
</script>
```

Can you please try below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="content" style="background-color: white;">
         <style>
            p{
            font-size:27px;
            }
         </style>
         <h3>Sample h3 tag</h3>
         <p style="color:red;">Sample pararaph</p>
      </div>
      <div id="editor"></div>
      <button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
      <script>
         window.onload=function(){
         $('#cmd').click(()=>{


         var pdf = new jsPDF();
         pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("content"),function() {
          pdf.save('web.pdf');
         });
         })

         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is giving more errors jspdf.min.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
    at g (jspdf.min.js:65)
    at Object.f.fromHTML (jspdf.min.js:75)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (?id=8:448)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery-1.12.3.min.js:3)

Comment: Can you please copy code once again because < removed by mistake, it's working code. I have changed code. And it's workable code

Comment: It is downloading a blank white page. how should i fix it?

Comment: Can you please change your question and add html in your question because here pdf generating properly...

Comment: Yeah ok. It is working  but css is not rendering. How to download pdf with css?